# Summation over permutations

Tags: summation, permutations, products

I've the following formula (taken from Hong Qian - Fractional Brownian Motion
and Fractional Gaussian Noise):

$$
\sum_P \prod_{j=1}^n E[X_j, X_{P_j}]
$$

where the sum runs over all permutations P: j → Pj of the positive integers j.

I tried to make an example in the case $n=4$:

$$
\sum_P \prod_{j=1}^4 E[X_j, X_{P_j}]
=
\sum_P E[X_1, X_{P_1}] E[X_2, X_{P_2}] E[X_3, X_{P_3}] E[X_4, X_{P_4}]
$$

Can you tell me how to continue?

---

EDIT: alternative way to write the above formula (from Wikipedia):

$$
\sum_{p \in P_n^2} \prod_{i, j \in p} E[X_i X_j]
$$

where the sum is over all the pairings of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, i.e. all distinct ways of partitioning $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ into pairs ${\displaystyle \{i,j\}}$, and the product is over the pairs contained in $p$.

Comment: Well what are the 24 permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$?

Comment: Hello @ancientmathematician the result is made by three terms, each of them is a product $E[] \, E[]$. Why Do i need 24 terms?

Comment: I don't think I understand the question after all. You say "where the sum runs over all permutations $P: j\mapsto P_j$ of the positive integers". Did you really mean that, or did you mean "where ... of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$". If you meant what you said then all these sums are going to be infinite ...

Comment: @ancientmathematician I copied that sentence from the paper I cited. I didn't understood it, for this reason I need an explanation

Comment: Yes, but you must be able to say whether they made a small slip and meant the finite sum -- the rest of us can only guess.

Comment: @ancientmathematician see the edit please

Comment: The edit would help if you said what $P_n$ means. Also I don't understand why it used to be $E[X_i,X_j]$ and it's now $E[X_i X_j]$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician in the paper and on wiki there aren't explanations, I reported everything

Comment: I can't even find the formula in Wikipedia: links to your references might help.

Comment: @ancientmathematician it's here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem#:~:text=If,.%5B5%5D%5B6%5D

Comment: Ah, so there's a lot more hypotheses about the $X_i$ than you had told us.

Comment: So from the alternative form in terms of pairings the answer for $n=4$ is as per the wiki that there are three terms in the sum, one for each pairing of the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Each of the terms is a product like $E(X_1 X_2)E(X_3 X_4)$. I can't see from the wiki why the original expression is meant to be equal to this one, it has 24 terms each a product of four covariances.